# Check if one list contains element from the other in groovy

Tags: groovy

i have 2 list

```
List<Car> cars
List<Car> filteredCars
```

and in cars

```
{ 
 {
   "uuid":"1234",
   "name": "A"
 },
 {
   "uuid":"2222",
   "name": "B"
 }
}
```

and in filteredCars

```
{ 
     {
       "uuid":"1234",
       "name": "A"
     },
     {
       "uuid":"3333",
       "name": "C"
     }
}
```

Now i want to add add filteredCars in cars by and then car should contains there object only (A,B,C)

i am try to implement this using groovy closure

```
filteredCars.each {
                if (!cars.contains(it)) {
                    cars.add(it)
                }
      }
```

and but by using this it added the duplicate objects
Any efficeent way to implement this in groovy without using two nested loops?

Comment: `def knownCars = cars*.name.toSet()` then `if (!knownCars.contains(it)...`

Comment: can i apply this on uuid because uuid will be unique for Cars but name can be duplicate

Comment: Have you tried it? Also it's `...contains(it.name)...` above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your list objects/maps there your approach would only work if the objects themself are compareable (which they are most likely not).  So it might be easier to just build an index of the known items for a quick lookup.  E.g.

```
def knownCarsIds = cars*.uuid.toSet()
```

Then only add if such an id ist not known:

```
...
if (!knownCarIds.contains(it.uuid)
...
```